# How to fill missing values in a column by random sampling another column by other column values

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, missing-data

I have missing values in one column that I would like to fill by random sampling from a source distribution:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
source = pd.DataFrame({'age':5*[21],
                       'location':[0,0,1,1,1],
                       'x':[1,2,3,4,4]})
source

    age location    x
0   21  0   1
1   21  0   2
2   21  1   3
3   21  1   4
4   21  1   4

target = pd.DataFrame({'age':5*[21],
                       'location':[0,0,0,1,2],
                       'x':5*[np.nan]})
target
    age location    x
0   21  0   NaN
1   21  0   NaN
2   21  0   NaN
3   21  1   NaN
4   21  2   NaN
```

Now I need to fill in the missing values of x in the target dataframe by choosing a random value of x from the source dataframe that have the same values for age and location as the missing x with replacement. If there is no value of x in source that has the same values for age and location as the missing value it should be left as missing.

Expected output:

```
    age location    x
0   21  0   1 with probability 0.5 2 otherwise
1   21  0   1 with probability 0.5 2 otherwise
2   21  0   1 with probability 0.5 2 otherwise
3   21  1   3 with probability 0.33 4 otherwise
4   21  2   NaN
```

I can loop through all the missing combinations of age and location and slice the source dataframe and then take a random sample, but my dataset is large enough that it takes quite a while to do.

Is there a better way?

Comment: your example is a bit ambiguous, can you provide the expected output?

Comment: Answer was edited.

Answer (score 0):

You can create `MultiIndex` in both DataFrames and then in custom function replace NaN by another DataFrame in [`GroupBy.transform`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.DataFrameGroupBy.transform.html) with [`numpy.random.choice`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/random/generated/numpy.random.choice.html):

```
source = pd.DataFrame({'age':5*[21],
                       'location':[0,0,1,1,1],
                       'x':[1,2,3,4,4]})

target = pd.DataFrame({'age':5*[21],
                       'location':[0,0,0,1,2],
                       'x':5*[np.nan]})
```

---

```
cols = ['age', 'location']

source1 = source.set_index(cols)['x']
target1 = target.set_index(cols)['x']

def f(x):
    try:
        a = source1.loc[x.name].to_numpy()
        m = x.isna()
        x[m] = np.random.choice(a, size=m.sum())
        return x
    except KeyError:
        return np.nan
       
       
target1 = target1.groupby(level=[0,1]).transform(f).reset_index()
print (target1)
   age  location    x
0   21         0  1.0
1   21         0  2.0
2   21         0  2.0
3   21         1  3.0
4   21         2  NaN
```

Answer (score -1):

You can create a common grouper and perform a `merge`:

```
cols = ['age', 'location']


(target[cols]
       .assign(group=target.groupby(cols).cumcount())               # compute subgroup for duplicates
       .merge((# below: assigns a random row group
               source.assign(group=source.sample(frac=1).groupby(cols, sort=False).cumcount())
                     .groupby(cols+['group'], as_index=False)       # get one row per group
                     .first()
              ),
              on=cols+['group'], how='left')    # merge
       #drop('group', axis=1) # column kept for clarity, uncomment to remove
)
```

output:

```
   age  location  group         x
0   20         0      0  0.339955
1   20         0      1  0.700506
2   21         0      0  0.777635
3   22         1      0       NaN
```

Comment: Sorry I was unclear in my example. There can be multiple missing values in target with the same values of age and location.

Comment: @ArtturiBjörk I just commented on that ;) it should be easy to adapt however

Comment: If you could adapt your answer for the case where there can be multiple instances with the same values for age and location I would really appreciate that. This is exactly the problem I'm struggling with :)

Comment: @ArtturiBjörk how is my solution not working for you?

Comment: It doesn't match the values of age and location

Comment: @ArtturiBjörk I updated the answer, it should work as expected

Comment: I made the working example a bit more general. There aren't necessarily the same number of values in the source as there are missing in the target. The values that replace missing ones need to be random with replacement(!) from the source.

Comment: @ArtturiBjörk you should provide all details from the beginning… this avoids spending time on an *in fine* non matching answer :(

Comment: OK thanks for your feedback! :) It's difficult to anticipate all possible "shortcuts" that can be used in a minimal working example.